# How to show that the space of regular differentials forms on $\mathbb{A}^n$ for $n \geq 1$ is an infinite dimensional $k$-vector space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Definition: Let $X$ be a quasi-projective variety and let $K=k(X)$ be the field of rational functions on $X$. We call elements of $\Omega_{K / k}^1$ rational differential forms on $X$. $A$ rational differential form $\omega$ is regular at $x \in X$ there is an open neighbourhood $x \in V \subset X$ and regular functions $f_i, g_i \in k[V]$ such that $\omega=\sum f_i d g_i$.

So I was just trying to show this by contradiction and assumed we had a finite dimensional space and showed we would get some kind of contradiction. But because everything is locally defined on open sets, it was hard to work with these objects and I am not sure what exactly we contradict. How should one approach this problem?

Comment: That's kind of an unwieldy definition for what you want to do, so you should upgrade your definition. Show that a regular differential form on an affine variety $X$ is of the form $\sum f_idg_i$ for $f_i,g_i$ regular functions on $X$. Now the calculation will be much easier.

Comment: I would not approach this by contradiction.  You can write down all the differentials explicitly and see directly how many there are.